# Slow Open Dialog user Interface in Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: front-end

The other day I noticed an interesting problem with Mathematica on the Mac.  When I'm in the Mathematica application and try to open a mathematica file with the "Open" option of the file menu the open dialog box will appear as expected.  However if I have to go several folders deep in my filesystem hierarchy to a folder with many mathematica files the operation of the open dialog box will bog down to an unusable point.  The symptoms are as follows.  When I try to scroll through the list of available files the window and the Mathematica app will freeze for 20-30 seconds.  It will then jump unpredictably to around the list and freeze again for another 20-30 seconds.  This repeats itself over and over rendering it impossible to open the file that I really wish to open.

I opened the MacOS activity monitor while this is occurring and found that the coreservicesd process zooms out of control and takes over 80-90% of the processor clock cycles and that the com.apple.IconServicesAgent takes up most of the remaining clock cycles.  My guess is the the Mathematica front end for some reason doesn't play nice with Mac OSX Mavericks.  I think that it is specific to Mathematica though because I've not noticed any problem with other applications.

Anyone have a similar experience or a fix?

Comment: I was also having this problem with OS X 10.9 when running Mathematica and/or other applications as well. I upgraded to OS X 10.9.1 yesterday, and as far as I can tell the problem has now gone away.

Comment: I've upgraded to 10.9.1 and the problem remains!

Comment: After using OS X 10.9.1 for a while now, I have noticed that lists of filenames sometimes take a while to appear, but the severity of the problem is less than it was in OS X 10.9.